# 2005 Chrysler Town and Country sliding door

Tags: chrysler, door, town-and-country, van

The passenger side sliding door motor doesn't stop when it opens. It continues to run until you deactivate it by pulling on the handle. What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Inspect your wire harness as explained in [this video](https://youtu.be/IUrq4x2NS6E). Basically, remove the cover, remove the clips and slide the harness around. Look for broken or frayed wires.